# Post Multiple images using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

When i Post multiple image using angular js it didnot post on server
but when i post single image it works perfectly 
please Help me to out of this problem
below is my code

```
var jsonData=$scope.form;
        $http({
            method: 'POST',                                                     
            url: Serve.base + '/groupview/' + $scope.groupid,                             
            headers : { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: function (data) {
            data._method = 'PUT';
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("model", angular.toJson($scope.form));
            console.log(data);
            console.log($scope.form.gallery_image);
            JSONObj = $scope.form.gallery_image;
            jQuery.each(JSONObj, function (j, files) {
                console.log(files)
                console.log(j)
                jQuery.each(JSONObj[j], function (k, file) {
                    console.log(file)
                    console.log(k)
                    formData.append('upload_image'+k, file);
                });
            });
```

Comment: i'm not sure, but maybe you forgot the enctype="multipart/form-data" attr on your form

Comment: already added in form 
single image its working fine
issue when posting multiple image

Comment: could you provide us the outputs of your console.log in the code?

Comment: [File, File, File, File, File, File, File, File]
group.js?a:152 File {name: "Chrysanthemum.jpg", lastModified: 1247549551674, lastModifiedDate: Tue Jul 14 2009 10:32:31 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 879394…}
group.js?a:153 0
group.js?a:155 Chrysanthemum.jpg
group.js?a:156 name
group.js?a:155 1247549551674
group.js?a:156 lastModified
group.js?a:155 Tue Jul 14 2009 10:32:31 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

757:4030 Success

Comment: if it's possible, please, edit your question and add the outputs, isn't easy to read in the comment